# Impossible to close Cursor when setting to SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

Im performing certain database operations after which I attach Cursor to the SimpleCursorAdapter for display List on my ListActivity. If I close the cursor in finally block (or anywhere after the code below), nothing is displayed in the list

```
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
          R.layout.list_row, cursor,
          new String[] { Constants.KEY_TITLE }, new int[] { R.id.text1 });
```

If the cursor is not closed, Android throws exception when activity makes request to another activity or is passivated.

PS I tried closing cursor inside onPause(), but android complains before onPause is called.

Answer (score 4):

You have to leave open the cursor on your finally block.

You missed out to call in your activity.

```
startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

This will make sure the activity manages the Cursor for you.

Comment: For those who stumble upon, on newer versions of Android, `startManagingCursor` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I get around this by creating the cursor on the fly.  It appears that the SimpleCursorAdapter will manage the cursor for you.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
      R.layout.list_row, db.query(...),
      new String[] { Constants.KEY_TITLE }, new int[] { R.id.text1 });
```

Also since Pentium10's post, startManagingCursor has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

That only solves part of the problem. When I startManagingCursor(cursor); and hit Menu key > menuActivity then > back key I get:

```
ERROR/Cursor(4047): Invalid statement in fillWindow()
```